# dotnet publish with single file option still copy appsettings.json and web.config files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

how to reproduce this problem:

1. use .net 7 sdk to create an asp.net core webapi project
2. modify .csproj file to same with below:

```xml
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
        <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <EnableCompressionInSingleFile>true</EnableCompressionInSingleFile>
        <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>true</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
        <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

3. use this command to publish: `dotnet publish -r win-x64`
4. you can find these files in publish dir:

- appsettings.Development.json
- appsettings.json
- DemoProject.exe (i only want this file)
- web.config

is there any way to include `appsettings.json`,`appsettings.Development.json` and `web.config` file?

Comment: The point of these config/settings files is that you can edit them. Including them in the executable would make this very difficult. Have you tried just deleting them and testing again? Maybe they are optional.

Comment: @Lynn as far as I know，springboot (a java framework) will package settings file into jar file, and you can override some settings by create a new settings file around jar file ,  it seems a little hard to implement this behavior in aspnetcore

Comment: If you are selecting windows as the target, it will generate the web.config which is used for IIS hosting. If you select osx or linux it will not generate the web.config file. But appsetting.json will always generate by default.  If you don't want it, you could delete it and write all the settings inside the program.cs. \

Answer (score 0):

`<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>` will not purely create a single exe.

Instead, It will create a self-extracting exe with an embedded zip file which will extract the all required files to a temporary path and then start executing the exe.

The structure of `appsettings.json` and `web.config` are based on the Microsoft's recommended best practices to run ASP.NET code for easy maintenance. You can always remove this if you want.

If you use **Kestrel** instead of IIS, you are free to remove the `web.config` file.

Additionally use can get rid of appsettings file if you override the default behaviour by hard coding the default setting inside the code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/webapplication?view=aspnetcore-7.0